# Are spirits an inherently magical concept?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, barbarian, spirits

The [Geminate Invoker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo-barbarian-archetypes/geminate-invoker-barbarian-archetype/) Barbarian archetype involves inviting spirits into your body to gain totem rage powers, but RAW nothing about it directly contradicts the [Superstition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/rage-powers/paizo-rage-powers/superstition-ex) tree of rage powers, which focuses on rejecting and sundering all sorts of spells and enchantments.

That being said, would a barbarian that hates magic but also lets spirits power him up be a walking contradiction of a class? Just how magical are spirits considered in a world of high fantasy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Spirits have (essentially) nothing to do with magic

Undead in Pathfinder/Golarion *can* be created by magic, but far more commonly (easily exemplified by [Haunts](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/haunts/)) they result from traumatic things happening when a living creature, or group of creatures, dies. The process is not innately magical; you cannot cast Dispel Magic to disassociate a poltergeist.

The closest thing this would be called is a divine process; the life cycle of a [soul](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Soul) is overseen and propelled by various gods, mostly primordial beings but also [Pharasma](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Pharasma), who judges most souls (and is held with honor among the Shoanti, notable because they have a prominent culture of Barbarians), and [Groetus](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Groetus), who awaits the true death of the last mortal soul.